# I found my google compute instance in terminated state

Tags: google-compute-engine, systemd

I found this lines in /var/log/auth.log ( Ubuntu 15.04 )

```
Aug  6 20:46:52 <> systemd-logind[641]: Power key pressed.
Aug  6 20:46:52 <> systemd-logind[641]: Powering Off...
Aug  6 20:46:52 <> systemd-logind[641]: System is powering down.
Aug  6 20:46:53 <> sshguard[1440]: Got exit signal, flushing blocked addresses and exiting...
Aug  6 20:46:53 <> sshd[1419]: Received signal 15; terminating.
```

What does it mean? Who or what turn off my instance?

Comment: Do you maybe have [terminateOnHostMaintenance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#onhostmaintenance) enabled?

Comment: Did you try using `gcloud compute operations list` to determine if the shutdown is triggered by (or correlated with) a user operation?